# use enum inside layout in mvvm pattern

Tags: android, android-layout, mvvm

How could I use

```
class public enum AttacheType {
                VIDEOCAMERA, VIDEOGALARY, PHOTOCAMERA, PHOTOGALARY
 }
```

in the indicated part of the code?

```
      <import type="CreatePostViewModel.AttacheType" />
     </data>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Add_Video_ImageViewk"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.1"
         android:onClick="@{ () -> viewModel.addAttachment("HERE PLEASE")}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="attachType"
            type="com.packagename.CreatePostViewModel.AttacheType"/>
    </data>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Add_Video_ImageViewk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:onClick="@{ () -> viewModel.addAttachment(attachType.VIDEOGALARY)}"/>
</layout>
```

add your enum with full packagename and class

Comment: `com.packagename.CreatePostViewModel.AttacheType` need to change with your class path

Comment: I am already added it, this just for example <import type="CreatePostViewModel.AttacheType" />

Comment: what is package name for `CreatePostViewModel` ?? please open this file and check first line `package com.example.CreatePostViewModel;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Put the Enum into your `Resource` file:-

```
<attr name="AttacheType" format="enum">
         <enum name="None" value="VIDEOCAMERA"/>
         <enum name="One" value="VIDEOGALARY"/>
         <enum name="Two" value="PHOTOCAMERA"/>
         <enum name="Three" value="PHOTOGALARY"/>
</attr>
```

Use it like as:-

```
app:AttacheType="Two"
```